# How to fetch a JSON API response with 6000+ objects in a JSONArray

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a JSON API which is returning 6000+ objects in a JSONArray.

I've implemented Rxjava calling a retrofit GET API call. There isn't any error, but just a sentence stating *"Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=19KB"*.

How do I get the API data? Can I increase the cache for the retrofit response?

Comment: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=19KB this means your app gonna freeze or crash because of out of memory

Comment: did you solve this problem, i wondered the answer

Comment: Not yet, still looking for a solution, tried Padmini answer, didn't help. Need to try @Ferhat answer having a problem in sending context to the retrofit class.

Comment: you can send context while creating retrofit instance

Comment: Yes but I have messed it up with dagger and android components. Currently, the retrofit module is injected in the viewmodel class. Have to find a way to try that solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file you can set it like below, `android:largeHeap="true"`:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo4"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
```

But a phone with limited RAM capacity or old phones will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is providing pagination then better use pagination, because 6000+ data is huge. Your app's performance will degrade, and you will probably also receive an out of memory (OOM) exception and in low connection scenarios your app always receives a timeout issue.

One solution is you set your timeout in minutes `.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`, use @Sagar Vekariya code. And don't call your API in the **main thread**; better use a coroutine.

```
fun methodName(callback:(ArrayList<Bean>)->Unit) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         val list = get6KData()
         callback.invoke(list)
    }
}
```

You can do one more thing. Don't convert a response in Objects; just take it as a simple JSON text file. That will solve your OOM issue. Later parse the JSON content and insert in the database directly and fire a query in the database and use pagination to list in the app. For example,

```
fun methodName() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         val json = get6KData() // Get JSON text here
         parsingNinsertDB(json)
         // Here you can return the first batch or use another common method for pagination
    }
}


fun pageMethod(pageNo:Int,callback:(ArrayList<Bean>)->Unit) {
     GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     val list = db.get6KData(pageNo)
     callback.invoke(list)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a coding challenge, don't think they will provide pagination if I ask. Thanks anyways

Comment: If its a coding challenge then follow my answer, because if you directly convert into object then its 6k object thatswhy its giving you Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=19KB issue, thats the trick, mostly people use the same approach that you are using.

Comment: Where am I supposed to use the GlobalScope launch code?

Comment: you can call in any method, make sure your get6KData() is suspend method, basically here it will wait for the result once you get the result parse and insert in your db

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure configuring your cache size will solve your problem but you can increase cache by configuring your Client. If you are using OkHttpClient, you can do it something like this

```
val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
//pass context here
val cacheDir = File(context.applicationContext.cacheDir, "someChildName")

//Required Cache size
val DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50MB
val cache = Cache(cacheDir, DISK_CACHE_SIZE)

//You can use .cache() to configure your Client
clientBuilder.cache(cache).build()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
builder.addInterceptor(logging);
builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .setLenient()
     .create();

OkHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(httpClient)
        .build();
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help